# ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater using an Array named "name'. With other name it's work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is the problem, when tha variable is named 'name', the error 'dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater' appear!

But, why!? Here is the code:

**app.js**

```
var galleryModule = angular.module ("gallery",[]);
var name = ['Juan Manuel Jimenez','Carlos ALberto','Choko Barrios','Cota','Huevo'];

galleryModule.controller("appController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.names = name;
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="gallery">
<head>
    <title>
        GALERIA
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="JS/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="appController">
     <div ng-repeat="n in names">
        Bienvenido: {{n}}
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But, here is the thing, if you change in the second line in **app.js** *name* by *something* and also inside of appController.
The code will work! That's wierd for me.

**Update:**
I've fixed my problem. I am using the *name* varible in the global scope, so I was having troubles with the windows.name

Then, the solution that I've choose was use a *clousure* like:

```
(function() {
    var galleryModule = angular.module ("gallery",[]);
    var name = ['Juan Manuel Jimenez','Carlos ALberto','Choko Barrios','Cota','Huevo'];

    galleryModule.controller("appController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
            $scope.names = name;
    }]);
})();
```

**Thank you all! :)**

Answer (score 0):

**Dear**,

i think you should define name array within controller scope. And you'll get rid of the problem. And one other thing you should make some changes in $scope too. Only define it as parameter of function. Use minimal of [] brackets if possible.

```
var galleryModule = angular.module ("gallery",[]);

galleryModule.controller("appController", function($scope) {
     var name = ['Juan Manuel Jimenez','Carlos ALberto','Choko Barrios','Cota','Huevo'];
        $scope.names = name;
});
```

**Thanks & Cheers**